# Let $G$ be a planar graph with $V$ vertices such that each vertex has degree exactly $5$. What is the least possible value of $V$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a planar graph with $V$ vertices such that each vertex has degree exactly $5$. What is the least possible value of $V$?

---

Am I missing anything here?  I feel like I should know some formulas to help me.  The only formula I know is Euler's formula, but how is that going to help?  Diagrams won't guarantee anything, and they could be messy.  Solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the Euler's formula that $E \le 3V - 6$. Now use the fact that $E = \frac 12 \sum_{v \in V} d(v) = \frac 52 V$. Therefore we have that:

$$\frac 52 V \le 3V - 6 \implies 12 \le V$$

Therefore the minimum value of $V$ is $12$. Now it only remains to prove that such a graph exist.